# Count of User having at least five book

Tags: sql, database

How Can I count the number of members who borrow at least five book in library management system.
My system

```
Circulation(Memberid,Circulationid,Bookid)

Member (Memberid,Staffid,Studentid)
```

How can I get the answer?
Plz Give Me some hint

Comment: While homework / assignment questions are ok, there is an expectation that you would at least show us what you have tried so far, what about it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please post some more information and flesh out your question? You will get a better answer if you tell us what DBMS you are using, provide a sample of your data and an example of what you expect your solution to look like. It would also be helpful to see what you have tried yourself.

Answer (score -1):

try to use join to get both table data
and by using group by you able to get the count by using having clause

```
Select * from Member M
join Circulation C on M.Memberid = C.Memberid
GROUP BY C.Memberid
HAVING COUNT(C.Memberid) > 4
```

you can use COUNT(*) also